# Prevent useState value from being reset when props change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that looks something like this:

```
//@flow
import React, { useState } from "react";

type Props = {
  likes: int,
  toggleLike: () => void,
};

const Foo = (props: Props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const style = `item${open ? " open": ""}`;
  return (
    <div className={style} onMouseOver={() => setOpen(true)} onFocus={() => setOpen(true)} onMouseOut={() => setOpen(false)} onBlur={() => setOpen(false)}>
      <button onClick={props.toggleLike}>Toggle like</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Foo;
```

The `open` state is used to apply the "open" class when moused over. The problem comes if I call the `toggleLike()` prop function, since this updates the props and the component is rerendered with `open` reset to false. As the style uses a transition, this results in the animation rerunning as it changes back to false, then to true due to the mouse being over it.

So, how can I prevent `open` being reset back to `false` on each subsequent render? It seems like it should be straightforward, but after going through https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state I can't seem to apply it in my case.

Comment: That's not how React works, I guess you unmount the component on `toggleLike` which causes the state to reset. Just don't do it. Also, its better if you provide codesandbox: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash No, it's not unmounting the component on `toggleLike`. There's an HOC that handles that - the call triggers an AJAX request and updates its own state, which is passed to this component as props.

Comment: The problem is obviously in the parent at part of the code you don't show. And again, this claim is not true: "since this updates the props and the component is rerendered with open reset to false"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

State *does not* reset when props change. State is on a per component basis and is preserved throughout re-renders, hence being called "state".

As Dennis Vash already mentioned, the problem is most likely caused by the component being unmounted or replaced by an identical component. You can verify this easily by adding this to your component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Mounted")
}, [])
```

You should see multiple "Mounted" in the console.

If there's no way to prevent the component from being replaced or unmounted, consider putting the state into a context and consume that context inside your component, as you can also wrap each of your components into its own context to give it a unique, non-global, state.

Comment: Yep, looks like it was being replaced by an identical component